# What does First class (fare class F) on Jetstar Airways mean?

Tags: air-travel, fare-class, jetstar

A friend of mine recently booked a multi-city one-way ticket covering three airlines that according to ITA Matrix includes this mysterious segment:

[image]

Note that this is described as "First (F)", even though Jetstar is a low-cost carrier, doesn't offer more than Economy and Business, and [their GDS guide doesn't recognize a fare class "F"](http://agenthub.jetstar.com/~/_media/5FBB317BD6D9459E8AFC4FD16D3474D5.pdf).  The rest of the itinerary is also all "Economy (S)", which is a Starter Plus fare.

Any idea what kind of seat she's actually going to end up in, and how this happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't first class, it is a mistake made by ITA Software (unusually) in mapping the booking class (`F`) back to the cabin class (for JQ, booking class `F` is economy). A similar mistake is made by a few online travel agents for Aer Lingus which also uses `F` for economy.

Looking at ExpertFlyer it seems that JQ uses `J` and `D` for business; `Y`, `B`, `V`, `T`, `S`, `R`, `Q`, `P`, `O`, `N`, `M`, `E`, `F`, `L`, `A`, `Z`, `I`, `K` and `H` for economy, in order from most to least available.

The GDS guide you've linked is from 2014, they may have amended their codes since then; or it may be that the F class is not used for publicly sold fares.

You may want to report it to ITA as a bug.

Comment: Of all the letters in the alphabet to choose from, they just had to use F for a mid-cost economy fare didn't they? I mean, they knew Y and B were full-fare, so they weren't ignorant of the conventions used by everyone else in the industry; they just didn't care.